# Header Files in Multiple Directories: Best Practices

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

#### I'm a C Newb

I write lots of code in dynamic languages (javascript, python, haskell, etc.), but I'm now learning C for graduate school and I have no idea what I'm doing.

#### The Problem

Originally I was building all my source in one directory using a makefile, which has worked rather well.  However, my project is growing and I would like to split the source into multiple directories (unit tests, utils, core, etc.).  For example, my directory tree might look like the following:

```
.
|-- src
|   |-- foo.c
|   |-- foo.h
|   `-- main.c
`-- test
    `-- test_foo.c
```

`test/test_foo.c` uses both `src/foo.c` and `src/foo.h`.  Using makefiles, what is the best/standard way to build this?  Preferably, there would be one rule for building the project and one for building the tests.

#### Note

I know that there are other ways of doing this, including autoconf and other automatic solutions.  However, I would like to understand what is happening and be able to write the makefiles from scratch despite its possible impracticality.

Any guidance or tips would be appreciated.  Thanks!

#### [Edit]

So the three solutions given so far are as follows:

- Place globally used header files in a parallel `include` directory
- use the path in the `#include` satement as in `#include "../src/foo.h"`
- use the `-I` switch to inform the compiler of include locations

So far I like the `-I` switch solution because it doesn't involve changing source code when directory structure changes.

Comment: +1 for -I switch, it's most flexible way to go.By the way there is no problem to put common headers in dedicated include directory(good practice any way) and use -I to provide a path to that directory(flexibility) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For test_foo.c you simply need to tell the compiler where the header files can be found. E.g.

```
gcc -I../src -c test_foo.c
```

Then the compiler will also look into this directory to find the header files. In test_foo.c you write then:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

**EDIT**:
To link against foo.c, actually against foo.o, you need to mention it in the object file list. I assume you have already the object files, then do after that:

```
gcc test_foo.o ../src/foo.o -o test
```

Comment: This will not include foo.c though right?  I should just make sure I include it as a dependency for building test_foo.c?

Comment: Do you want to include foo.c literally? The this also works, i.e. #include "foo.c". If you want to link against it you have to list it in the object list.

Comment: I can see how this works when using the compiler - but how would intellisense know where the header files are?

Comment: Partly answering my own question: If one uses cmake and vscode, then `c_cpp_properties.json` can include the following key value pair: `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"` i.e. the cmake-tools extension can read cmake (which defines what directories are provided to the compiler with the `-I` option via `target_include_directories`) and can thus tell intellisense which directories to search through for header files

Answer (score 2):

I also rarely use the GNU autotools. Instead, I'll put a single hand-crafted makefile in the root directory.

To get all headers in the source directory, use something like this:

```
get_headers = $(wildcard $(1)/*.h)
headers := $(call get_headers,src)
```

Then, you can use the following to make the object-files in the test directory depend on these headers:

```
test/%.o : test/%.c $(headers)
    gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(flags) -Isrc -g -c -o $@ $<
```

As you can see, I'm no fan of built-in directives. Also note the `-I` switch.

Getting a list of object-files for a directory is slightly more complicated:

```
get_objects = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(1)/*.c))
test_objects = $(call get_objects,test)
```

The following rule would make the objects for your tests:

```
test : $(test_objects)
```

The `test` rule shouldn't just make the object files, but the executables. How to write the rule depends on the structure of your tests: Eg you could create an executable for each `.c` file or just a single one which tests all.

Comment: to get the object files from the source files, you can also simply do:
SRC_OBJECTS := $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing this is for header files used by a single C file to be named the same as that C file and in the same directory, and for header files used by many C files (especially those used by the whole project) to be in a directory `include` that is parallel to the C source directory.

Comment: Would I be using `-I` to tell gcc about these files as in quinmars' answer?

Comment: You have two options.  Either you use a relative path from the source file to the include file, or you don't include any path at all in the #include line and you use '-I'.  Your choice.  I've seen both done.

Answer (score 0):

Your test file should just include the header files directly using relative paths, like this:

```
#include "../src/foo.h"
```