# Organising code in c++

Tags: c++

I just moved from java to c++.
I was little confused about organising the source code.

In Java we have packages to organize between each module .

What are some common ways to organize the c++ source code?

Comment: How this is done is very much a question of personal preference. I tend to put related files in separate folders. much like separate packages. I've seen projects with hundreds of source files in the same folder, and everything in between.

Comment: I usually see a single `src/` directory, with then a subfolder that kind of denotes your "package". So the package `com.mydomain.server.login` for example in Java might equate to `src/server/login` in C++. It's really a matter of preference though. I've also seen people split out the header files into an `include/` path to keep them separate from the source files.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718126/best-folder-structure-for-c-cross-platform-library-and-bindings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at large open source projects in C or C++, you will find a large variety of ways to organise the source. However, a couple of common scenarios is to use a directory structure of `module` (or `component`) with `src` and `include` within each `module`. Alternatively, you can have it the other way around, and use `src\module` and `include\module`.

If you have test-code, that often goes into a `module\test` or `test\module`.

One of the interesting challenges with larger C++ projects is "where to put the header files that are shared between components". Sometimes there is a `include\public` (or `public\include`), sometimes they are with their respective component.

It can be quite useful to separate out the parts of a component that are "available for others to use" vs. those components that are only used internally - because something internal can be easily changed with no or minimal effect on other components, where something that is "visible" outside of the component will need more care - what happens if a component is published as a DLL and you update the DLL without recompiling the source in the parts that use the component [if you have third party clients that don't have your source code (or at least aren't likely to build it regularly), you don't necessarily want to force them to rebuild their projects every time you make some change.

For large projects, `namespaces` are used to prevent nameclashes.

Answer (score 0):

Partial response :

You can firstly organize your files in different folders, like in Java. When you #include an header file, you will type relative/path/from/src instead of path.of.the.package.

C++ also supports namespace concept : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 0):

First and obvious rule: if you're working on a team/collaborative project, follow the explicit (written best practices of your organization) or implicit (study how it has been done) rules of the project.

If you're on a project on your own, you have a lot of freedom in C++ because of different complementary organizational notions:

- namespaces,
- classes,
- filesystem folders,
- source files

Bacause you have a lot more freedom than in java I recommand mapping folders to namespaces and files to classes where reasonable:

- Use a .h / .cpp pair for each class, but you can also include helper classes or other linked classes if it seems logical and avoids having a lot of small files.
- Group classes in namespaces, and concerned files in a folder with the name of the namespace.

This way the client can write something like:

```
#include "groupA/subgroupB/classC.h"
using namespace groupA;
subgroupB::classC object;
```