# Best (cleanest) way for writing platform specific code

Tags: c++, qt

Say you have a piece of code that must be different depending on the operating system your program is running on.
There's the old school way of doing it:

```
#ifdef WIN32
   // code for Windows systems
#else
   // code for other systems
#endif
```

But there must be cleaner solutions that this one, right?

Comment: I hate conditional compilation. Hate hate hate. I prefer common header and separate implementation files. Cleaner, easier to follow, and usually minimal code duplication. For example, oswrapper.h, oscommon.cpp, osposix.cpp, oswindows.cpp and sort out which of osposix and oswindows gets built and linked in the makefile or IDE's target/profile/whatever.

Comment: I have to second the above post. Only rarely will I use `ifdef` directives, and that's if ONE operating system out of many has a peculiar quirk that can be quickly understood and fixed by anyone looking at the code and reading a short comment. In those situations, the cognitive overhead of separating everything into multiple files is far greater than the `ifdef` and a comment.

Comment: The cleanest way is to find a portable library that already implements what you need.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Have any such libraries on hand for hardware support, drivers, etc? That's not a very helpful general statement.

Comment: @Dogbert I have seen enough needlessly unportable code and enough people doing work that was done over and over before that I can say "Look for a suitable and portable library first" *is* good advice. I did not claim that any problem a programmer can encounter is already solved.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Your answer suggests one should look for an existing solution. What if one doesn't exist? That answer doesn't help.

Comment: @Dogbert If that comment was supposed to be an answer I would have posted it as answer. But it was not, it is simple advice to use existing code instead of e.g. writing yet another header that fiddles with `__int64` on Windows.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Fair enough.

Comment: Qt uses PIMPL idiom for platform specific things. https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer

Answer (score 4):

The typical approach I've seen first hand at a half-dozen companies over my career is the use of a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL).

The idea is that you put the lowest level stuff into a dedicated header plus statically linked library, which includes things like:

- Fixed width integers (`int64_t` on Linux, `__int64` on Windows, etc).
- Common library functions (`strtok_r()` vs `strtok_s()` on Linux vs Windows).
- A common data type setup (ie: typedefs for all data types, such as `xInt`, `xFloat` etc, used throughout the code so that if the underlying type changes for a platform, or a new platform is suddenly supported, no need to re-write and re-test code that depends on it, which can be extremely expensive in terms of labor).

The HAL itself is usually riddled with preprocessor directives like in your example, and that's just the reality of the matter. If you wrap it with run-time `if`/`else` statements, you comilation will fail due to unresolved symbols. Or worse, you could have extra symbols included which will increase the size of your output, and likely slow down your program if that code is executed frequently.

So long as the HAL has been well-written, the header and library for the HAL give you a common interface and set of data types to use in the rest of your code with minimal hassle.

The most beautiful aspect of this, from a professional standpoint, is that **all** of your other code doesn't have to ever concern itself with architecture or operating system specifics. You'll have the same code-flow on various systems, which will by extension, allow you to test the same code in a variety of different manners, and find bugs you wouldn't normally expect or test for. From a company's perspective, this saves a ton of money in terms of labor, and not losing clients due to them being angry with bugs in production software.

Comment: Your answer is good, but it seems to me that not all platform-mitigation code can be referred to as "HAL". For instance, when dealing with not-hardware-related OS differences, such as `Sleep(DWORD milliseconds)` and `sleep(uint seconds)`. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Marc.2377 For something like that, you'd just wrap them with your own `sleep()` function, with a common time base. IE: `xsleep(xUint64_t nanoseconds)`. All of your code uses this function, and your platform specific build of HAL **translates** it :)  The only time where this has issues is if you're trying to work with vastly different systems (ie: systems with different threading, security, networking models, etc). In that case, writing the HAL becomes a lot more difficult.

Comment: Indeed, and I once did exactly that. My comment, however, is specifically about using the "HAL" term to refer to abstraction layers not related to hardware at all.

Comment: @Marc.2377 It's sometimes referred to as "PAL", but "HAL" is a somewhat generic term that gets thrown around a fair bit, and generally means OS and architecture abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

An adopted practice for non-trivial projects is to write platform-specific code in separate files (and in separate directories, where applicable), avoiding "localized" `#ifdef`s to the fullest possible extent.

Say you are developing a library called "Example" and `example.hpp` will be your  library header:

*example.hpp*

```
#include "platform.hpp"

//
// here: platform-independent declarations, includes etc
//


// below: platform-specific includes    

#if defined(WINDOWS)

#include "windows\win32_specific_code.hpp"
// other win32 headers

#elif defined(POSIX)
#include "posix/linux_specific_code.hpp"
// other linux headers

#endif
```

*platform.hpp* (simplified)

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
#define WINDOWS
#elif defined(UNIX) && !defined(WIN32)
#define POSIX
#endif
```

*win32_specific_code.hpp*

```
void Function1();
```

*win32_specific_code.cpp*

```
#include "../platform.hpp"

#ifdef WINDOWS  // We should not violate the One Definition Rule
#include "win32_specific_code.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Function1()
{
    std::cout << "You are on WINDOWS" << std::endl;
}

//...

#endif /* WINDOWS */
```

Of course, declare `Function1()` in your `linux_specific_code.hpp` file as well.

Then, when implementing it for Linux (in `linux_specific_code.cpp`), be sure to surround everything for conditional compilation as well, similar to I did above (eg. using `#ifdef POSIX`). Otherwise, the compiler will generate multiple definitions and you'll get a linker error.

Now, everything an user of your library must do is `#include <example.hpp>` in their code, and place either `#define WINDOWS` or `#define POSIX` in their compiler's preprocessor definitions. In fact, the second step might not be necessary if the environment already defines either `WIN32` or `UNIX`. This way, `Function1()` can already be used from the code in a cross-platform manner.

---

This approach is pretty much the one used by the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/). I personally find it clean and sensible. If, however, you don't like it, you can have a read at [Chromium's conventions for multi-platform development](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/conventions-and-patterns-for-multi-platform-development) for a somewhat different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do a lot of this sort of stuff in my career, supporting code that buils and runs on an embedded device, plus in windows, and then also have it run on different ASICS and/or revisions of ASICS.

I tend to do what you suggest and then when things really diverge, move on to defining the interface I desire to be fixed between platforms and then having separate implementation files or even libraries.   It can get really messy as the codebase gets older and more exceptions need to be added.

Sometimes you can hide this stuff in header files, so your code looks 'clean', but a lot of times that's just obfuscating what's going on behind a bunch of macro magic.

The only other thing I'd add is I tend to make the #ifdef/#else/#endif chain fail if none of the options are defined.   This forces me to revisit the issue when a new revision comes along.   Some folks prefer it to have a default, but I find that just hides potential failures.

Granted, I'm working in the embedded world where code space is paramount (since memory is small and fixed), and code cleanliness unfortunately has to take a back seat.